# Can I use samtools addreplacerg to replace multiple RG entries at the same time?

Tags: sam, samtools

I have a bam file that contains two @RG lines:

```
@RG     ID:Foo.Bar_L1.Foo   PU:Bar_L1.Foo SM:Foo        PL:Illumina     LB:Library.fa
@RG     ID:Foo.Bar_L2.Foo   PU:Bar_L2.Foo SM:Foo        PL:Illumina     LB:Library.fa
```

I wish to replace it with one @RG line:

```
@RG     ID:Foo SM:Foo        PL:Illumina     LB:Library.fa
```

What is the best way to do this?

samtools addreplacerg looks useful, but it looks like I can only affect one @RG per call, and I have no desire to write out the whole bam file twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about samtools, but [picard AddOrReplaceReadGroups](http://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/command-line-overview.html#AddOrReplaceReadGroups) can clear existing read groups and write a new one.